# Perform arithmetic operation on specifc values of Array - PHP

Tags: php

I have an array

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 34
    [1] => 04:32 PM
    [2] => 05:32 PM
    [3] => MNL | ITLY
    [4] => 2h 10m
    [5] =>   PHP 9,222
    [6] => 33
    [7] => 04:32 PM
    [8] => 04:32 PM
    [9] => ITLY | MNL
    [10] => 2h 10m
    [11] =>    PHP 7,227
)
```

how can i perform arithmetic operation on value of index 5 and 11.

Comment: What is the logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using preg_replace you can strip the 'PHP' part and the comma from value.

```
echo preg_replace('|  PHP (\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $array[5]) + preg_replace('|  PHP (\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $array[11]);
```

or if the number of spaces is random '\s' is any whitespace char

```
    echo preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $array[5]) + preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $array[11]);
```

or str_replace()

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: hey bro 1 more. for example i need to perform multiplication for the value of preg_replace $array[5]  to specific number. I tried preg_replace('|  PHP (\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $array[5]) * 3; IT returns me 0 value. @Catalin Minovici

Comment: You mean like this ? `php > echo preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', '  PHP 9,222') + 500000000;
500009222
php > echo preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', '  PHP 9,222') * 2;
18444`

Comment: So `echo preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', ' PHP 9,222') * 2;` equals 18444 as you can see. I think the reqex is good. PS: use the one with \s it's more elegant

Comment: preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $value[5]) * $variable_number . still it returns me 0 bro

Comment: Check the value of $value[5] maybe it's null or something. Check this http://ideone.com/lmYhEU

Comment: foreach ($fare as $key => $values) {
    $amzf = preg_replace('|\s+PHP\s+(\d+),(\d+)|', '$1$2', $values[5]) * $passenger;
    $numbezramf = number_format($amzf);
    echo $numbezramf;
   }
    ?> // it gives me 0 value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136587/discussion-between-catalin-minovici-and-mistaken-identity).